# how to play video file in popup window in android?

Tags: android, popup, media-player, android-videoview

I want to play any video file in popup window in android device. Also, I have to show the video from a Fragment and not from an Activity.

Using `mVideoDialog = new Dialog(this);` didn't work for me. It throws this error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

I tried to fix it by passing `getActivity()` to the Dialog, but the app crashes with the same error. What should I do?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/Z9XGbKyE

Comment: can you show what have you written your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go for a custom dialog, add this code -

```java
Dialog mVideoDialog;
VideoView mVideoFullScreen;
MediaController controller;
```

Create a method -

```java
mVideoDialog = new Dialog(this);
mVideoDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mVideoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
mVideoDialog.setOnKeyListener(this);
mVideoFullScreen = (VideoView) mVideoDialog.findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
controller = new MediaController(this);
HelloWebViewClient webViewClient = new HelloWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contentEquals("file:///android_asset/01")) {
            showVideo(01); //check user click url from webview and pass int
        }
        else if (url.contentEquals("file:///android_asset/02")) {
            showVideo(02);//pass int to determine which video to play
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DDD URL: "+url.toString()); view.loadUrl(url);  
        }
        return true;       
    }
```

Show video method to play the video file -

```java
public void showVideo(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (i==01) {
        mVideoDialog.show();
        mVideoFullScreen.setVideoPath("file:///sdcard/video file name.m4v");
        controller.setMediaPlayer(mVideoFullScreen);
        mVideoFullScreen.setMediaController(controller);
        mVideoFullScreen.requestFocus();
        mVideoFullScreen.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        mVideoFullScreen.start();
    } else {  }
}
```

Comment: mVideoDialog = new Dialog(this);
since i have to make this code for a fragment not for Activity so above line doesnt work for me.. this is showing error."android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?" 

i tried to troubleshoot it by passing getActivity() but still same error.. app get crashed with same eror. what should i do?